# Work with result query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In Mysql I have this kind of result from my query

```
+-id-+-name--+is_active-+---date---+
|  1 | name1 |     1    | 21231321 |
|  3 | name3 |     1    | 11313213 |
|  4 | name9 |     1    | 10313213 |
|  8 | name3 |     1    | 10013213 |
| 54 | name2 |     0    |    0     |
| 9  | name5 |     0    |    0     |
| 11 | name8 |     0    |    0     |
```

I want to make multiple selects from this result query without selection this query again.

From the result query above I want to extract this three conditions in one

```
1.Give me first two rows (result query above is sorted by date)
2.Give me one random row where is_active = 1 and not in results in 1.
3.Give me one random row where  is_active = 0
```

I read about `database views` and `stored procedures` , but I don't know if this is best way ?

Can someone provide me MySQL code for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Views : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html . Not enough?

Comment: How big is your result set typically, and what kind of application code are you working with? (php, ruby, whatever).  If the result set is large but the query isn't intensive, I would probably execute 3 queries. But if the result set is pretty small, I would probably load all the results in application code and figure it out there.

Comment: On the application side for a small result set, this is as easy as fetching all rows, pulling off the first 2, looping over and splitting the array where is_active changes from 1 to 0, then picking randomly from those.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski my result set will be 50-100 results and I working with php

Comment: It will not be possible to include all these three conditions in one single mysql query. Because the next two queries depends on the output result for first query. So without running query one you cannot run condition 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small results set, 50-100 rows as stated in the comments, PHP's array processing facilities can handle your requirements quite easily.  Assuming your rowset was sorted in the query output

```
ORDER BY 
 date DESC,
 is_active DESC
```

... you can fetch all rows into one array in PHP using whichever API you are using:

```php
// To store output:
$results = array();

// Using the appropriate fetch call (assuming an associative array here)
while ($row = $result_resource->fetch()) {
  // append row onto results
  $results[] = $row;
}

// Remove the first 2 - your first requirement:
$first_two = array_splice($results, 0, 2);

$active = array();
$inactive = array();
// Then split the remaining into is_active or not is_active with a loop
foreach ($results as $r) {
  if ($r['is_active'] == 1) {
    $active[] = $r;
  }
  else $inactive[] = $r;
}

// Then you can just call `array_rand()` to get results from those
$rand_active = array_rand($active);
$rand_inactive = array_rand($inactive);
```

I'll state again that all this depends on the rowset being small. The overhead of the array and loops is probably going to be less than multiple query calls.  However, if the rowset is large, I would use 3 separate queries.

The first:

```
ORDER BY 
  date DESC
  is_active DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Fetch the rows from that query and get the ids. Execute again with:

```
WHERE
  is_active = 1 
  /* the 2 ids from the first query */
  AND id NOT IN (id1, id2)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

And the third query:

```
WHERE is_active = 0
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

All three of these *could* be packed together into a single `UNION ALL` query, but I would consider that only if performance was really poor.